# Is it possible to connect to Oracle 9i data source in SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, oracle-9i

We're doing a migration from Oracle 9i to SQL Server 2008. So I'm thinking of a way to move the data from Oracle and I thought about SSIS. I'm new to this Microsoft's technology and I would like to know whether it's possible to specify Oracle 9i as a data source, and do I need any further installations in case it's possible ?

Answer (score 2):

You can connect to Oracle from SSIS. You have to install Oracle client on your development and also on your production environments. After doing proper tnsnames configurations you can use odbc source or ado.net source.

Comment: Could you please give more details ..? Thanks by the way ;)

Comment: I did a quick search on the internet. I found many blog posts about Sql Server 2008 and BIDS have some problems about connectivity. some files needed to be copied manually some Registry keys needs to be updated.

Comment: I used Sql Server 2012 and Data Tools I installed Oracle Client on development environment. There is a file named [TnsNames.ora] (http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Tnsnames.ora) I added the connectivity properties to that file and I used Ado.Net source as source. that simple. I'm looking for a link to share right now.

Comment: have you found something ? Thanks man in advance ;)

Comment: For basic SSIS you can watch the video series on youtube. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3cPq9FXk-RA&list=PLNIs-AWhQzcmPg_uV2BZi_KRG4LKs6cRs

Comment: For installation and configuration of oracle client and attunity drivers you can read this link (https://masteringbiztalkserver.wordpress.com/2014/06/29/ssis-connecting-to-oracle-using-attunity-connector/)

Answer (score 1):

I have used 2 tools to perform Oracle to SQL data migrations:

The first is the Oracle to SQL Server Migration Assistant (SSMA).  It is a fairly basic tool and if you don't have any binary objects to migrate it is ok.  It allows you to create the schema and migrate the data, but it isn't the fastest tool in the world and the OLE drivers wont work with binary objects.  I find it ok for small basic databases with no binary data.

The second is writing SSIS packages and using the Oracle Attunity drivers, these are excellent and work with binary object types.  More importantly they are extremely fast and will connect to any Oracle from 9.2.0.4 onwards.  They really are tuned for performance and are many times faster than SSMA.

Comment: I have tried SSMA and I can say its not suitable for my needs :) do you have any good tutorial on how to use SSIS and how to install the oracle attunity drivers ?

Comment: You can download the attunity drivers at https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=29283.  As for the good tutorial you do really need to learn SSIS.  It is a huge topic and something that a quick tutorial isnt going to be enough.  You need to get someone skilled in SSIS in to write the packages for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your should use Oracle client 8.xx to 10.x.x installed in your Windows 2003 server. Then you can use SSIS running in SQL Server 2008 to migrate your data.